# How to display more listview items in the same line?

Tags: android, listview, contacts

I would like to display 2 listview items in the same line, like favourite contacts in the default phone app. I do not need a full working solution, but only a guideline what to do.

Illustration:
[image]

There is a list of favourite contacts and there are 2 contacts (illustrated only by pictures) in 1 line.

Thanks!

Comment: in my favorites there is only one item per line(Samsung Galaxy S3), Could You explain it a little bit more detailed?What should be shown in one line?

Comment: I added a picture of my favourite contacts.

Comment: this is not looking like a listview, it looks like any layout with fragments

Comment: how yould you achive the same functionality? (dinamic set of data displayed like above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own adapter to handle this, or you can use a `GridView`.

To use the custom `Adapter` strategy:

1. Create a row layout that has space for two elements.

In xml, for whatever you now consider one 'row', make a horizontal `LinearLayout` that can hold two of them next to each other.  That's your new definition of a row.

1. In your `Adapter`, fill each row with two elements from your data set instead of the usual 1.

Take care to handle the case where the data set only has one element left.

Your alternative is to use a `GridView`,

Comment: Tanks, `GridView` did the trick. I only had to change the `ListView` to `GridView` and set `android:numColumns="2"` and that was all. Thanks!